# How does raphael.js work with older browsers if they don't support SVG?

Tags: raphael

Raphael uses SVG for rendering, which is only supported on IE9 (and not even fully). How does it render on IE6-8? I can't find any mention of this on the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not mistaken; Raphael makes use of Internet Explorer's [VML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) feature for <= 8. VML was Microsoft's version of SVG before they decided to drop development of VML (but continue to support it) in favor of SVG. In fact, search the [home page](http://raphaeljs.com/) for "VML" and that is what they say:

> Raphaël ['ræfeɪəl] uses the SVG W3C Recommendation **and VML** as a base for creating graphics. This means every graphical object you create is also a DOM object, so you can attach JavaScript event handlers or modify them later.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Oh! I guess I missed that. I saw VML and assumed it was the name of the markup language used to define SVG graphics. Thanks.